# How to import struct members from Solidity Library

Tags: solidity, struct, library, import

Trying to implement the diamond upgrade following Nick Mudge implementation in aave. Been getting this error (**struct member not found or not visible after argument dependent lookup in struct**) importing the AppStorage struct. Any idea why?

LibAppStorage.sol

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.1;

struct AppStorage {
    uint96 applicationCount;
    mapping(uint96 => Application) applications;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => bool)) applicantGrant;
    mapping(uint96 => mapping(uint48 => MilestoneState)) applicationMilestones;
    mapping(uint96 => Workspace) workspaces;
    mapping(uint96 => mapping(address => bytes32)) memberRoles;
    }
library LibAppStorage{
function blabla.....
}
```

Application.sol

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.1;

import {AppStorage} from "../libraries/LibAppStorage.sol";

function submitApplication(
        address _grant
    ) external {
        require(!AppStorage.applicantGrant[msg.sender][_grant], "XXX");
......
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the full snippet code. You should use **AppStorage** pattern like the following code below:

**LibAppStorage.sol**

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.1;

struct AppStorage {
    uint96 applicationCount;
    mapping(uint96 => Application) applications;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => bool)) applicantGrant;
    mapping(uint96 => mapping(uint48 => MilestoneState)) applicationMilestones;
    mapping(uint96 => Workspace) workspaces;
    mapping(uint96 => mapping(address => bytes32)) memberRoles;
    }
library LibAppStorage{
    function appStorage() internal pure returns (AppStorage storage ds) {    
        assembly { ds.slot := 0 }
    }
}
```

**Application.sol**

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.1;

import {AppStorage} from "../libraries/LibAppStorage.sol";

contract Application {
    AppStorage internal s;
    function submitApplication(
            address _grant
        ) external {
            require(!s.applicantGrant[msg.sender][_grant], "XXX");
            ......
    }
}
```

**AppStorage** struct is always available at storage slot of **0**. if you want to access to it create a new storage variable like this `AppStorage internal s;` .Or by calling `LibAppStorage.appStorage()` from **LibAppStorage.sol**

**If it's useful please vote the answer up**